# Writing an install script for CentOS

Tags: linux, shell, centos

Every time I deploy a VPS server, I install VNC server.

But every time I have to do this:

```
yum groupinstall Desktop
yum install tigervnc-server
yum install vnc
yum install firefox
```

(etc.)

Can I write an automated **.sh script/file** (or something else) that
I could run on every server to install VNC server automatically? If
so, how?

Comment: For a start version, put those lines in a file myPosInstall and do  `sh myPosInstall`. Next add first line  `#!/bin/bash` , `chmod 755 myPosInstall` and do `./myPostInstall`

Answer (score 2):

You would need to make a simple script (say "*setup*"). Just type `text_editor_of_choice setup` and then add these lines:
`#!/bin/bash`
`yum groupinstall Desktop`
`yum install tigervnc-server`
`yum install vnc`
`yum install firefox`
Et cetera... 
Then save the file and type `chmod +x setup` to make it executable. Now all you have to do is run it with `bash setup`.
Cheers,
*Interesting...*

Comment: You don't actually need to `chmod +x setup` if you're invoking the script via the `bash` executable. You'd only need to add execute permissions if you're executing the script directly, e.g. `./setup`